# Why am I getting this error with MinGW and Cmake?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw

So I am trying to compile this flip fluids addon with blender, so I followed this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVKM1egDoGs , So I first ran `cmake.exe -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..` and it was telling me that it was missing a CMakeLists File... So I added one... then I ran `cmake.exe --build .` and it got to 3 percent than showed me errors like ...

```
In file included from C:/Users/N/Downloads/Blender-FLIP-Fluids-master/src/engine/threadutils.h:29,
                 from C:/Users/N/Downloads/Blender-FLIP-Fluids-master/src/engine/meshlevelset.h:65,
                 from C:/Users/N/Downloads/Blender-FLIP-Fluids-master/src/engine/meshobject.h:30,
                 from C:/Users/N/Downloads/Blender-FLIP-Fluids-master/src/engine/fluidsimulation.h:38,
                 from C:\Users\N\Downloads\Blender-FLIP-Fluids-master\src\engine\c_bindings\fluidsimulation_c.cpp:25:
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/mutex:93:9: note: previous definition of 'class std::recursive_mutex'
   class recursive_mutex : private __recursive_mutex_base
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Users/N/Downloads/Blender-FLIP-Fluids-master/src/engine/mingw32_threads/mingw.condition_variable.h:25,
                 from C:/Users/N/Downloads/Blender-FLIP-Fluids-master/src/engine/threadutils.h:31,
                 from C:/Users/N/Downloads/Blender-FLIP-Fluids-master/src/engine/meshlevelset.h:65,
                 from C:/Users/N/Downloads/Blender-FLIP-Fluids-master/src/engine/meshobject.h:30,
                 from C:/Users/N/Downloads/Blender-FLIP-Fluids-master/src/engine/fluidsimulation.h:38,
                 from C:\Users\N\Downloads\Blender-FLIP-Fluids-master\src\engine\c_bindings\fluidsimulation_c.cpp:25:
C:/Users/N/Downloads/Blender-FLIP-Fluids-master/src/engine/mingw32_threads/mingw.mutex.h:142:44: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef class std::_NonRecursive<std::recursive_mutex> std::mutex'
```

This is the full error https://pastebin.com/KTnALG1E, where is this coming from?? is it a mingw error or what? Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Your full error message includes a more interesting bit:

> C:/Users/N/Downloads/Blender-FLIP-Fluids-master/src/engine/mingw32_threads/mingw.thread.h:32:2:
> error: #error This version of MinGW seems to include a win32 port of
> pthreads, and probably already has C++11 std threading classes
> implemented, based on pthreads. It is likely that you will get class
> redefinition errors below, and unfortunately this implementation can
> not be used standalone and independent of the system  header,
> since it relies on it for std::unique_lock and other utility classes.
> If you would still like to use this implementation (as it is more
> lightweight), you have to edit the c++-config.h system header of your
> MinGW to not define _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS. This will prevent system
> headers from defining actual threading classes while still defining
> the necessary utility classes.

So either install a different version of mingw or edit your mingw files according to the instructions above.

Comment: So since there is a mingw32_threads folder, I have to download the 32 bit version? How do I do that?